# Crear archivo de texto en ruta especifica para FileWriter Java

Tags: java, filewriter

Estoy precisando exportar los datos de varios **JTextField** y lo he logrado utilizando **FileWriter**, el problema que tengo *es que deseo crear el archivo desde el programa*, ***quiero que el usuario antes de exportar el archivo, elija el nombre del archivo de txt y donde desea guardarlo***.
Ajunto una captura de la ventana y el codigo que utilizo para exportar los datos seleccionados de los jtextfield. Espero su ayuda. Gracias de antemano.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    private void exportarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    FileWriter fichero = null;
    try {
        //PRUEBA EXPORTAR
        fichero = new FileWriter("/Users/x/MySQLexport.txt");
        fichero.write("""
                      DATOS DE CONEXION:
                      """);
        fichero.write("Host: " + host.getText() + "\n");
        fichero.write("User: " + user.getText() + "\n");
        fichero.write("Password: " + pass.getText() + "\n");
        fichero.write("DataBase: " + db.getText() + "\n");
        fichero.write("Port: " + port.getText() + "\n");
        System.out.println("El fichero se creeo correctamente: MySQLexport");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fichero.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione utilizando **JFileChooser()**; para seleccionar el nombre del archivo, y donde deseo guardarlo, espero que les sirva el aporte:
**Importar lo siguiente:**

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.awt.Component;
```

**Y el codigo me quedo de la siguiente manera:**

```
   private void exportarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    FileWriter fichero = null;
    try {
        
        JFileChooser directorio = new JFileChooser();//Creo directorio
        directorio.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);//Selecciono el directorio
        //Guardo el directorio
        Component parent = null;
        int returnVal = directorio.showSaveDialog(parent);
        //if= Si el directorio seleccionado es aprobado
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String selectPath = directorio.getSelectedFile().getPath();//Almaceno la ruta
            System.out.println("El directorio que eligió es:" + selectPath);//Muestro donde se guardara
            fichero = new FileWriter(selectPath);//El archivo se guardara en la ruta seleccionada.
            fichero.write("""
                      DATOS DE CONEXION:
                      """);
            fichero.write("Host: " + host.getText() + "\n");
            fichero.write("User: " + user.getText() + "\n");
            fichero.write("Password: " + pass.getText() + "\n");
            fichero.write("DataBase: " + db.getText() + "\n");
            fichero.write("Port: " + port.getText() + "\n");
            System.out.println("El archivo se grabo correctamente en: " + selectPath);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fichero.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Me ayudo el siguiente articulo: https://programmerclick.com/article/56971863130/